# how to install sharp AR-6023NV

Tags: networking, command-line, printing, ubuntu-drivers

how to install sharp AR-6023NV printer in ubuntu 22.04?  It seems there is no any driver for Ubuntu 22.04. Suggest please Regards.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [sharp-ar-6023n-printer-driver](http://www.sharp-printerdrivers.com/sharp-ar-6023n-printer-driver-download/) ?
If the printer can be used with MacOS, it could be "driverless" and work with cups "out-of-the-box".

Comment: If the maker has no driver and it does not work with CUPS then you will be out of luck.